# how to set width which is equal to another widget on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view

I need to draw a horizontal line below a text field such that the width of the line equals the text width (not the width of the full screen).

In my app I have a textview below a view(Horizontal line).
The **width of the line view** should be equal to the **width of the textview**.
I tried android:layout_width="wrap_content" and "match_parent", which does not solve the problem.

This is xml coding sample:

```
         ......
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="PopUpWindow"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
             ......
```

image of the screen is:

[image]

please help me.

Comment: You could programmatically get the width of your textview, via its `LayoutParams`, then apply this width to your horizontal line, also using `LayoutParams`. You 'll find *lots* of examples for setting width in Java.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you use a `RelativeLayout` you can use the `align`-attributes:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0.3dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: For better support for right-to-left layouts you should also add `android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"` and         `android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView1"`

Comment: what if I'm using LinearLayout?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade Check out some of the other answers below. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a Layout other than a RelativeLayout, you can match the widths of your widgets programmatically, such as in this example:

layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Here's some text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some more text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that both text fields are both set to wrap_content.

Main.java:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

if(tv1.getWidth() < tv2.getWidth())
    tv1.setWidth(tv2.getWidth());
else
    tv2.setWidth(tv1.getWidth());
```

If you have multiple widgets that you want to have a uniform width, just repeat the above code for the new element. For example, let's say there was a button I wanted to adjust the width to, to match the other elements:

```
if(tv2.getWidth() < button)
    tv2.setWidth(button.getWidth());
else
    button.setWidth(tv2.getWidth());
```

Comment: Give it a try and let me know. It worked for me so it should work for you too. I believe it should also do the commands if your user rotates their device orientation, so no matter how they're using their device your views will look great.

Comment: OMG, I was looking for this for half of my day. Thanks @Argus9

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use RelativeLayout then you can set parent's width to wrap content and parent's width will become equal to biggest child. Then you can set the width of the small child to match_parent and it'll match the width of required view.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/navHeaderName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/profile_progress_bar"
            android:text="This is a large text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@id/profile_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="45" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use RelativeLayout and use these two attribute in horizontal line view

```
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"




<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.23" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
            android:text="this is TextView" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:text="" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

What Jave said is correct - and the easiest, but what if you're not using a `RelativeLayout` to contain the View's ?

If you're customizing your UI within onCreate() then you'll find that obtaining the width from another widget will give you an incorrect result ! That's because the UI hasn't been set up yet.

But you can still set up your UI within onCreate... simply run code that executes after the UI is set up. This is achieved through use of the `View.post()` command.

**The XML :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="short string" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is a longer string" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
private Button mButtonOne;
private Button mButtonTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // inflate UI
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

    // get references to UI elements
    mButtonOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    mButtonTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_two);

    // Make buttons the same size (i.e. Button1.width = Button2.width)
    if ((mButtonOne != null) && (mButtonTwo != null))
    {
        mButtonOne.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                mButtonOne.setWidth(mButtonTwo.getWidth());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The result is that the Width of `button_one` will match the Width of `button_two`. This is a nicer look when the amount of text varies heavily between the two View's.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case.  If you plan to modify things in the layout dynamically and have them also sized the same as the TextView, you may want to wrap them in a parent view together.  If it's a one-time thing, use RelativeLayout as suggested by the other answer here.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ... > <!-- layout parameters as appropriate-->
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="PopUpWindow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use following width attribute.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="PopUpWindow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="0.3dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
```