# Expand one textview space with respect to another

Tags: android, textview

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Name."
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#c91799c9"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Paragraph"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#3f1799c9"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In the given code , I am having 2 textviews in a horizontal view .
I want that when text of one textview goes in another line, the another textview space should also be increased according to first one

[image]

As in given image paragraph can be in 3-4 lines, but I want Name textview should be expanded vertically

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set width which is equal to another widget on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977721/how-to-set-width-which-is-equal-to-another-widget-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

> Just give height to **match_parent**

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c91799c9"
        android:text="Name."
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#3f1799c9"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="paragraph"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**If you want the text in center you can add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in both textview.**

Comment: If this solves your problem then please upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Name."
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#c91799c9"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Paragraph"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#3f1799c9"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
 set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in both `textView` also you can set `Textsize` same in both `textView` `android:textSize="24sp"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#c91799c9"
    android:text="Name."
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#3f1799c9"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Paragraph"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give gravity centre to the first TextView.ie add below code to the First TextView 'Name'.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

And also change the height of both TextView to match_parent.

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to set the width after the layout is shown or you will get an
>   error, there is a command .onPost that you can use to avoid this
>   error.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> the java code must be places in OnCreate method but after
>   setContentView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ImageView my_image = findViewById(R.id.my_image);
Button bt_start = findViewById(R.id.bt_start);
EditText et_user = = findViewById(R.id.et_user);
if ((my_image != null))
    {
        my_image.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                bt_start.setWidth(my_image.getWidth());
                et_user.setWidth(my_image.getWidth());                                 
            }
    });
}
```

> In my example you get the imageview width using `my_image.getWidth()`
>   and set this value to other components like bt_start or et_user but
>   you can do it in any other component.

```
my_image != null
```

> can be change for any other boolean comparision like :

```
bt_start != null
et_user != null
```

> this is only to confirm the item you get the width from is not null so
>   you could get the width correctly, if this item was null you get a
>   null point exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:text="Name"
       android:textColor="#000"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:background="#c91799c9"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:textSize="17sp"
       android:paddingLeft="8dp"
       android:text="Paragraph"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textColor="#000"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:background="#3f1799c9"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```